# Python: Is it possible to have multiple exceptions statments for a try block?

Tags: python

```
try:
    case_no  = re.search("Case Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",br.response().read()).group(1)
except:
       try:
           try:
               case_no  = re.search("Citation Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",br.response().read()).group(1)
            except:
               case_no  = re.search("Citation Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",br.response().read()).group(1)
        except:
              case_no  = "N/A"
```

As you can see the above code is quite clumsy. I want to know if there is any way I can do like this.

```
try:
    XYZ
except:
    DOXYZ
except:
    DOXYZ
```

Basically I want to be able to use - "try X if exception then try Y if exception then try Z" without nesting too much statemtns.

Comment: It seems that you have several regexp's that you want to try in order until one can be successfully applied or you get to the "N/A" part. Why not store the regexps in a list or tuple and iterate through it, catching whatever exceptions you want on the way? And yes, you can have several except blocks if you specify what exception to catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you shouldn't be checking exception at all?

```
patterns = [
  "Case Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",
  "Citation Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",
  "Citation Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<"   # same as #2?
]
text = br.response().read()
case_no  = "N/A"
for pattern in patterns:
  res = re.search(pattern, text)
  if res:
    case_no = res.group(1)
    break
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is posible, as long as you define exception condition...

Like:

```
try:
    f = open('myfile.txt')
    s = f.readline()
    i = int(s.strip())
except IOError as (errno, strerror):
    print "I/O error({0}): {1}".format(errno, strerror)
except ValueError:
    print "Could not convert data to an integer."
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

But, you must define the exception type.

Comment: This isn't really what the OP's trying to do, though.

Comment: Yes, but basically, you can not execute try catch blocks as you execute switch or if blocks.

Using if or switch is better that try-except. Because purpose of using try-catch is not suitable for a such condition...

Answer (score 3):

A common idiom for the behavior you're looking for is something like:

```
try: foo()
except: pass

try: bar()
except: pass
```

But you should always catch a specific exception and make sure it makes sense. In your case it simply doesn't make sense - to see if the regular expression matched, test the result for `None`:

```
r = br.response().read()
PATTERN1="..."
PATTERN2="..."
PATTERN3="..."
mo = re.search(PATTERN1, r) or re.search(PATTERN2, r) or re.search(PATTERN3, r)
case_no = mo.group(1) if mo else "N/A"
```

For performance reasons you can precompile your regexes:

```
RE1 = re.compile("...")
RE2 = re.compile("...")
RE3 = re.compile("...")
mo = RE1.search(r) or RE2.search(r) or RE3.search(r)
```

Also, for your specific regex patterns you can easily combine them into one, and using a named group can help readability:

```
pat = r"""(Case|Citation) Number:</span></td><td><span class="Value">(?P<case_no>[^<]*?)<"""
mo = re.search(pat, r)
case_no = mo.group("case_no") if mo else "N/A"
```

And finally, using regular expressions to parse HTML [is the road to disaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), consider using [HTMLParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) from the standard lib or [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to do what you want. the semantics of multiple `except` clauses covers catching different types of exceptions that may be thrown from the **same block of code**. You must nest the statements or rethink your code to get the desired results.

This might be a case where it would be better to test for the preconditions that you expect to cause an exception.

```
if test1():
    #dox
elif test2():
    #doy
elif test3():
    #doz
```

etc.

I would also recommend against using catchall `except:` phrases except in very specialized circumstances where you know you need them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing the same or a similar thing in every try/except block, you might use a loop

```
case_no = "N/A"
for _ in range(3):
    try:
        case_no  = re.search("Case Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<",br.response().read()).group(1)
        break
    except SomeExplicitlyCaughtExceptions:
        pass
```

Of course it makes no sense in this form, because trying the same thing three times will yield the same result.

Comment: I imagine `br.response().read()` will be different each time.

Comment: That's not true.
If we're talking about a web service or a OS service you might want to perform the operation again in case it might be online and only log that the request timedout last time.

Comment: `case_no = "N/A"` should probably be indented?

Comment: Oh, there's a `read` in there ... I just copied the recurring line into my code and missed that. :) Edited to assign the default value at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off restructuring your code:

```
success = False

for _ in xrange(MAX_ATTEMPTS):
    try:
        XYZ
        success = True
        break
    except:
        pass

if not success:
   DOXYZ
```

It's better to explicitly specify the exception, though. Do you really want to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`s?

Comment: You probably want to break out of the `for` on success.

Comment: and after you `break` on success, you can use an `else` clause on the `for` to process the ` not success` case and drop that flag all together.

Comment: @aaronasterling - yeah, but almost no-one knows what an else clause on a loop in Python is for.

Comment: thats because almost nobody uses them

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid the exceptions if I were doing this:

```
count = 3
caseRe = re.compile("Case Number:</span></td><td><span class=\"Value\">([^<]*?)<")
while count > 0:
   text = br.response().read()
   mo = caseRe.search(text)
   if mo is None:
       count -= 1
       continue
   case_no  = mo.group(1)
   break

if count == 0:
    case_no = "N/A"
```